# Magento Get Shopping Cart and Catalog Price Rules

Tags: cart, catalog, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

I am trying to get all my Price Rules/Promotions so that I can loop through them and take their descriptions.

I Can't seem to get Shopping-Cart Rules and Catalog Rules in one request

IS it even possible?????

```
$catalogrules = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('description', 'notnull');
$cartrules = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_collection')->load
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('description', 'notnull');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
$catalogrules = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('description', 'notnull');

$cartrules = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('description', 'notnull');
```

they will be loaded automatically when you loop them through foreach

Comment: Thank You, but how would i loop through both of them at the same time?

Comment: Would something like this be smart?                                $collection1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(148)->getProductCollection(); 
$collection2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(149)->getProductCollection(); 
//load an empty collection (filter-less collections will auto-lazy-load everything) 
$merged = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',-1); 
//add items from the first collection 
foreach($collection1 as $item) { 
$merged->addItem($item); 
} 
//add items from the second collection
 foreach($collection2 as $item) {

Comment: you can make a single collection by union.. check this post:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/23777/15499